# VB6 Decompiling Problems

Tags: vb6, decompiling

I got to decompile a VB6 dll, got a decompiler (actually tried 4 of them), even paid for a pro license, but of course I ran into a problem: the retrieved code doest even look like the previous one and it looks like a lot of information is lost. I do understand it's a one way road, but maybe someone could technically explain to me why VB6 compiled dll loses some info in machine code which cannot be retrieved later on in the decompilation process?

Comment: The compiler will have restructered the flow of the source code for machine code, doing optimisations, removing any redundancy, converting variable names to symbolic tokens, ditching any comments etc. For example you could have source code written in two different ways that results in the same compiled code. So going back the other way, you will never get back to the exact original source. The decompiler will allow you to understand the processing being undertaken in the dll, but not much beyond that.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.

Comment: Second - so if we take Your scenario of the code optimised and changed in the compiled dll and then decompiled after and the source code taken and all libs included it should work as the primary one ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Decompilers cant produce original code theoretically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685370/why-decompilers-cant-produce-original-code-theoretically)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do unless the code was compiled with the option to compile to P-Code.  For example, if you look at http://www.vb-decompiler.org/ it clearly says that it will only work with the P-Code.

The issue is that VB6 by default will compile to machine code which doesn't translate to VB6.  You may be able to get the UI back because this is not code, but aside from that you are out of luck.